# Unpacking and Converting Bytes -Python

Tags: python

I am trying to unpack a file containing over `1 billion bytes` that encode integers which are 4 bytes each. So every 4 bytes is a different integer. I obviously need to chunk my code for such a big file. I currently have the following:-

```
import os
z =os.path.getsize(x)
import struct
with open(x, "rb") as f:
    while True: 
        this_chunk = min(50000000, z)
        data = f.read(this_chunk)
        ints1 = struct.unpack("I" * (this_chunk //4) , data)
        if not data:
            break 
    print(ints1)
```

I get an error which reads:-

> struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 50000000

Could you please help me understand this error and how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of your chunks read.  I'd recommend using expressive variables names instead of `x` and `z`.  The main problem is on your last read, where you want to read the amount of `sizeremaining`, not a full chunk.  Try this (untested)

```
filesize = os.path.getsize(x)
chunksread = 0
chunksize = 50000000
sizeremaining = filesize

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while sizeremaining > 0:
        this_chunk = min(chunksize, sizeremaining)
        data = f.read(this_chunk)
        ints1 = struct.unpack("I" * (this_chunk //4) , data)
        sizeremaining -= this_chunk
        if not data:
            break 
    print(ints1)
```

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: Your min function is not correct.  You should be comparing `min(50000000)` with the bytes remaining.  Let me modify my answer

Comment: Ya, it should.  What's it doing?

Comment: I just made an indentation error. Thank you for your help!